# Input shapes always incompatible with layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, input, shapes

I am very confused as to what the input shape needs to look like for my model. My training data looks like this `(2834, 270, 1)` where I have 2834 samples each containing 270 individual values. My targets are each one value (For example the number 2) and I want to train my model to accurately predict a target value for a given sample (which contains 270 individual values) Here is the code that I currently have:

```
train_data = np.asarray(train_data).astype('float32')
train_data = train_data.reshape(2834, 270, 1)
train_labels = train_labels.reshape(2834)
train_data = tf.cast(train_data, dtype='float32')
train_labels = tf.cast(train_labels, dtype='float32')
print(train_data.shape)
print(train_labels.shape)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_data.shape)))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(layers.Conv1D(32, 5, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(layers.Dropout(0.2))
model.add(layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='linear'))
model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-05), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
history = model.fit(train_data, train_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=1)
print(model.summary)
```

I have a 1d neural network (because my training data is 1 dimensional I think, could be wrong) that should output a single value, but my error occurs when I try fitting my model. It says that I have the incorrect input shape for one of my layers. The full error:

```
   ValueError: Input 0 of layer max_pooling1d_6 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 2834, 266, 64)
```

Comment: it seems you are looking for Conv1D and MaxPooling1D

Comment: Changed to 1d, thanks a lot. Could you elaborate though why it is 1d if the input is (x, x, 1)

Comment: Put code in google colab and share the link to look what;s wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=(train_data.shape)))
```

to:

```
model.add(layers.Conv1D(64, 5, activation='relu', input_shape=(266, 64)))
```

Comment: The input shape to the first layer should be the same shape as my data. (266, 64) is the input shape for maxpool1d as stated in the error.

Comment: No, the input shape SHOULD not be same as your training set. The `input_shape` is defined **ONLY** for instance NOT  for the whole training set. You need to define the batch size.